# Java Process.waitFor() not waiting for .bat files to complete and exiting process on windows 7- issue

Tags: java, batch-file

**Java Process.waitFor() not waiting for .bat files to complete and exiting process on windows 7 but working fine on linux for .sh files**
I am working on Java Process where I am supposed to invoke `.bat` files from windows. I developed this code inside linux and is working fine on linux but on windows when I invoke file with sleep of 5 seconds. It is locking and removing process at same time and not waiting for 5 seconds.

Can you please look into code and help me to figure out how can I inovke bat files efficently?

```
 public int processOutput(String absoluteFilePath, String phoneNo) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(absoluteFilePath);
        Map<String, String> map = builder.environment();
        map.put("phone_number", phoneNo);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                LOG.info(line);
            }
            LOG.info("Process Ended");
        }


        return process.waitFor();
    }
```

Comment: Start your process running the batch script by issuing `START /wait your_script.bat` which should wait until the script finishes

Comment: @diginoise thanks for comment. Now I am getting error that file not found

Comment: What are the contents of your batch file?

Comment: it is some cleaning resource in windows and takes almost around 15 min.

Comment: Does the batch file wait if you run it manually from the command line?

Comment: @IdontKnow was it running correctly before you added `START /wait` ? Maybe you have to provide the path to your script?

Comment: @diginoise, `START` is an internal command of cmd. how should java execute the internal command of something else by its own?

Comment: Try `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(System.getenv("ComSpec"), "/C", absoluteFilePath);` But you should first make sure that the batch files itself has no issues.

Comment: @sst thanks for reply. I tried your solution but now it started and I am not able to see any execution from batch file. I tried a sample dummy file which will exit after 5 seconds and now it is taking forever.